# What is the best way to open a file from Dropbox/Google Drive/iCloud Drive in an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I'm building an iOS app where the user will be opening/importing a PDF from multiple potential sources (iPad file system, iCloud Drive, Dropbox, Google Drive).  What is the best library/method for implementation of such a requirement?  UIDocumentPicker?

Comment: `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iCloud, that helps you to upload any doc or download any document using UIDocumentPicker But while using iCloud first of all you need to enable “iCloud containers” entitlement to your App ID. So go to the developer.apple.com and enable this to your app id you can follow below step to enable it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkTNo.png) or follow developer Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html

1. Go to your developer account.
2. Find the App ID you are working on
3. Click edit.
4. On the iCloud section select the radio button that says
       "Include CloudKit support (requires Xcode 6)".
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkTNo.png)

After this you need to go to Xcode project select Target and enable iCloud container as like in the attached screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SxVM.png)

Now, add this to your interface `<UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UIDocumentMenuDelegate>` then You can use the below code.

```
-(void)TapUploadFile
{
    //Create the file path of the document to upload
    NSURL *filePathToUpload = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Terms" ofType:@"txt"]]  ;

    //Create a object of document picker view and set the mode to Export
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *docPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithURL:filePathToUpload inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService];
    //Set the delegate
    docPicker.delegate = self;
    //present the document picker
    [self presentViewController:docPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

/**
 - *  This function is used to download the files from a destination(iCloud,Dropbox)
 - *
 - *  @param sender button object on which user has clicked
 - */

- (void)tapDownloadFile
{
    /** Create the array of UTIType that you want to support
     -     * Pass the array of UTIType that application wants to support. Add more UTType if you want to support more other than listed
     -     */
    NSArray *types = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,(NSString*)kUTTypeSpreadsheet,(NSString*)kUTTypePresentation,(NSString*)kUTTypeDatabase,(NSString*)kUTTypeFolder,(NSString*)kUTTypeZipArchive];
    //Create a object of document picker view and set the mode to Import
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *docPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    //Set the delegate
    docPicker.delegate = self;
    //present the document picker
    [self presentViewController:docPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)tapDocumentMenuView:(id)sender
{
    /** Create the array of UTIType that you want to support
     * Pass the array of UTIType that application wants to support. Add more UTIType if you want to support more other than listed
     */
    NSArray *types = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,(NSString*)kUTTypeSpreadsheet,(NSString*)kUTTypePresentation,(NSString*)kUTTypeDatabase,(NSString*)kUTTypeFolder,(NSString*)kUTTypeZipArchive,(NSString*)kUTTypeVideo];
    //Create a object of document menu view and set the mode to Import
    UIDocumentMenuViewController *objMenuView = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

    //Create Custom option to display
    [objMenuView addOptionWithTitle:@"My Custom option" image:nil order:UIDocumentMenuOrderFirst handler:^{
        //Call when user select the option

    }];
    //Set the delegate
    objMenuView.delegate = self;
    //present the document menu view
    [self presentViewController:objMenuView animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker {
    documentPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Delegate-UIDocumentPickerViewController

/**
 - *  This delegate method is called when user will either upload or download the file.
 - *
 - *  @param controller UIDocumentPickerViewController object
 - *  @param url        url of the file
 - */

- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport)
    {

        // Condition called when user download the file
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        // NSData of the content that was downloaded - Use this to upload on the server or save locally in directory

        NSString * str = [self base64forData:fileData];

        stttttt= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/pdf;base64,%@",str];

        //Showing alert for success
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully downloaded file %@", [url lastPathComponent]];

            //adding the doc name in the doc textfield
            NSString *docName = [url lastPathComponent];
            JVFloatLabeledTextField *attachment = (JVFloatLabeledTextField *) [self.view viewWithTag:222];
            [attachment setText:docName];

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"UIDocumentView"
                                                  message:alertMessage
                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        });
    }else  if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService)
    {
        // Called when user uploaded the file - Display success alert
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully uploaded file %@", [url lastPathComponent]];
            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"UIDocumentView"
                                                  message:alertMessage
                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        });
    }

}

/**
 - *  Delegate called when user cancel the document picker
 - *
 - *  @param controller - document picker object
 - */

-(void)documentPickerWasCancelled:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller {

}
```